# How can I create a sticker stick on div

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to create a sticker that stick on top of a div like this:

[image]

```
<div className="upgrade-premium">
<div className="upgrade-team">
    <h1>Premium</h1>
    <p>100 members</p>
    <p>Private Teams</p>
</div>
<div className="team-plan-premium">
    <span className="numb-passes">
    <Passes20 />
    </span>
    <span className="passes"> Passes</span>
</div>
</div>
```

How can I create it with css that make it stick on a div like that?

Comment: make your parent div position relative and this div (upgrade-premium div) position absolute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the **position** property of your outer element (.upgrade-premium) to **relative** first.

And then, set the **position** property of your sticker element to **absolute**, and set its **right** and **top**  properties to **0**, somehow like this:

```
.upgrade-premium {
    position: relative;
}

.sticker {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```